# How to be able to zoom with front facing camera

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, uigesturerecognizer

In my custom camera, I implemented a pinch gesture recognizer. Then i added a function for the video to be able to zoom. The camera zooms when I am on the back camera, but when i switch it to the front facing camera, I am not allowed to zoom. This is my function

```
var zoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
@objc func pinch(_ pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    print("123")
    guard let device = videoCaptureDevice else { return }
    func minMaxZoom(_ factor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat { return min(max(factor, 1.0), device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor) }

    func update(scale factor: CGFloat) {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }
            device.videoZoomFactor = factor
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }

    let newScaleFactor = minMaxZoom(pinch.scale * zoomFactor)

    switch pinch.state {
    case .began: fallthrough
    case .changed: update(scale: newScaleFactor)
    case .ended:
        zoomFactor = minMaxZoom(newScaleFactor)
        update(scale: zoomFactor)
    default: break
    }
}
```